# How to test multiple users concurrently?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I have been asked to test an exam system on the web. For this, I have to simulate the fact that 10, 100, 1000 students have entered the system and have solved the questions. What is the most appropriate method I should follow for this?

With Selenium, I opened a browser for each of 35-40 users and made them with separate threads, but this method did not make much sense. Because it is not possible for me to get 1000 users in this way and it is forcing the CPU so much.

Apart from that, I learned that there are tools such as JMeter that can perform performance and load tests, but I did not know if it would work properly. The aim is to help determine whether they have the required system competence when the product is given somewhere. If the system equipment needs to be upgraded, it will be upgraded accordingly, otherwise, it will remain.

I would be glad if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is a **browser** automation framework
- Browsers execute [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the responses

So you just need to ensure that JMeter is sending the same HTTP Requests as browser does, normally JMeter test plan is being built using following steps:

1. Record your test scenario using browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Perform [correlation of dynamic parameters and parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of test data (i.e. each virtual user should use its own credentials)
3. Ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing by running it with 1-2 virtual users/loops and inspecting request/response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
4. [Add more users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) and run the full load test for 10/100/1000/whatever users
5. Analyze the results using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

If you have existing set of tests which you can partially or fully re-use you can consider [converting your Selenium tests to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/)